# is there any database work like NTFS based on RBAC?

Tags: database, rbac

If somebody want to manage permissions in a program first idea would be RBAC implementation. but another idea is a **service** like NTFS which allow to any user to create and manage his/her directories and sub directories. moreover can add more users with defined access

Comment: CQRS design pattern

Comment: domain model design pattern

Comment: crud_rbac server